# Disable "Office 365 tips"

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365

Office365 Users in my organization are getting tips on a bar about how to "better collaborate" on a document. Most of them are in Excel and related to using PowerBI, Teams, OneDrive or another cloud service. We do not want them to be proactively pushed towards these features as they shouldn't use them for various reasons. If it helps, we are using an Office365 E3 license, and the installation is version 16.0.12527.20260 64bit.

Is there a way to turn them off e.g. using GPO?

We already have turned off "End user Communication" in the admin panel of Office365 (as described in https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/microsoft-will-soon-send-your-office-365-users-tips-and-training-emails/)

Any input is appreciated.

[image: Office 365 Tip]

Comment: Also try, in Options, General, "screen tip style" and turn that off. I am not certain because what you see may be more related to Microsoft Teams.

Comment: did you try : File->Options->Trust Center->Trust Center Settings Button->Message Bar, and unselect "policy tips", as described here: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2184238-how-to-disable-office-application-tips

Comment: also check: File -> account -> account privacy: manage settings -> "optional connected experiences". Probably you can also turn these off for all users using your admin control panel